Look up tab name in list, then depending on value copy/paste range from one source to another
I am creating an Excel schedule for a dental clinic and have written a macro that will create a new tab for each working day of the month.
I've created another macro that will list all the current tabs in the workbook. What I'm hoping to do next is to create another macro that will go through my list of tabs names and repeat itself until it comes upon a blank cell. The list is located on Tab "Calender" in Column AO Row 10 and goes downwards AO Row 11, etc.
This macro would then:

search for the tab name, for example "Mon.Jan.01"
on the "Calender" Tab Range C8:AG108, find it
then based on the value underneath it, in this case it would be "M1", it will then run another macro that will Copy/paste from Tab "Monday" Cells A3:O23 onto the tab "Mon.Jan.01".

Any assistance or guidance in how I can learn to do this if it is possible would be appreciated.
List of tabs:

Find date and pull value underneath it, base on value copy/paste from range onto the tab:



Welcome Peter! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!
